# Is there a way to set up a shortcut to call Build Tasks in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Currently, I have a Build Task set up in Visual Studio Code (not Visual Studio). When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, I get a list of my build tasks, I then have to select my task and then it will compile and run my program.

Is there an easier way to do this, so instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I can just press one button and have a preset Build Task run? Either a keyboard button or a GUI button will work great.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Mark the task as your default build task via *Terminal -> Configure Default Build Task...* This simply adds the following to the task in `tasks.json`:

```json
"group": {
    "kind": "build",
    "isDefault": true
}
```

After that, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> will run the task directly.

Additionally, you could also have a default *test* task with `"kind": "test"`. That task can be directly run with the `Tasks: Run Test Task` command (no shortcut assigned by default).

And finally, if having two shortcuts is still not enough (or you don't want to modify `tasks.json`), you can set up keybindings to [run tasks directly by their name](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "run"
}
```

Replacing `run` with the label of your Build Task.

To open `keybindings.json` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or click *File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts*. You may need to add `[]` if the file was previously empty.

Comment: First of all thank you, I'm now down to 3 button presses instead of 4 and I can do it with one hand. Where is `keybindings.json`? I tried adding it to my project's `.vscode` folder where the `tasks.json` file is, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Press Ctrl+K and Ctrl+S to open it, then add this, and the part you need to change is the "args" section.

Comment: @AaronFranke Are you able to set keybindings within your workspace in the `.vscode` folder?

Comment: Follow up question: Once you have created a default build task, how do you trigger *non*-default build tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code in `keybindings.json` located at `C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\`:

```
[
   {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+r",
      "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
      "args": "run"
   },
   // [...]
]
```

Source: https://lronaldo.github.io/cpctelera/files/buildsys/vscode_integration-txt.html