# How can I make a custom GUI button for a specific keyboad command in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make **a custom GUI button** for **a specific keyboad command** in vscode. I have read a related question's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143660/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-shortcut-to-call-build-tasks-in-vs-code). But it didn't answer about making **a separate GUI button**.

Suppose, I want to make a GUI button to run **tasks.json** whose keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: in an extension contribute a menu option and add an icon (SVG or PNG) (light and/or dark)

Comment: @rioV8 What is that extension's name?

Comment: any extension you make, currently only in `package.json` so not possible to do it with a setting